# Django tests apis model object does not exist

Tags: python, django, testing

I have created 2 Django models, a `User` model and a `Account` model. In the `User` model, I have all info and in `Account`, I have account details of that user.
I have designed Views that when I create a user, respective account object also created.
URLs: `/user/` will create new user and account object.
But when I am writing tests to check APIs, I created a new user. User object is accessible but when I access account detail it throws `models.object doesn't exist`.

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)

class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

def post(self, request):
    received_json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    user = User(user_name=received_json_data['user_name'], first_name=received_json_data['first_name'],
                last_name=received_json_data['last_name'], email=received_json_data['email'])
    user.save()
    account = Account(user=user);
    account.save();

class TestUser(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()
        user1 = {"email": "ram@gmail.com", "user_name": "ramu", "first_name": "ramesh", "last_name": "yadav"}
        data1 = json.dumps(user1)
        self.response = self.c.post('/user/', data1, content_type="application/json")
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200)
        account = Account.objects.get(pk =1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the account with primary key which might not exist.
You can try to get the account the following way:

```
account = Account.objects.filter(user__email="ram@gmail.com")
```

This will return all accounts for that user. `get` method will throw an error if one user has multiple account.

Comment: Hey maverick but i have api like 'account/id' where it will give details of that account. It is still showing same error there. Where get method implemented with pk.

Comment: This means your Account object didn't get created or you are using the wrong primary key. Check in the database whether the Account exists or not.

Comment: My all APIs are working fine in postman. Now I am writing test cases for these APIs. I am accessing client.get method for user account user which was created above.